# Any reason not to define a derivative as the average of the derivatives on all sides?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We all know $\operatorname{abs}$ is not differentiable in a classical sense, but one question that's always bothered me is, why not define the derivative as the average derivative in each direction? i.e., why not say:

$$f'(z) = \frac{f'(z^+) + f'(z^-)}{2}$$

Of course, for complex $z$, we can generalize this to

$$f'(z) = \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}\frac{1}{\theta}\lim_{\Delta z \to 0}\frac{f(z + e^{i\theta}\Delta z) - f(z)}{\Delta z}\,d\theta$$

It coincides with the classical definition wherever the original exists, and it has the same useful properties (e.g. linearity) while being more general.    It also seems intuitive.

So why not define it this way? Is it not useful? I don't imagine no one's tried it before!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative

Comment: The fundamental reason is that the mean value theorem fails. Any theory of differentiation without the MVT is useless.

Comment: Definitely could be useful somewhere but personally that doesn't seem very intuitive. The biggest issue I would have is that it is ambiguous what the derivative means. The derivative being zero gives you some information about the curve and you loose that if you could also have the absolute value function

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: That's a great point about MVT failing, but could you elaborate on why that is bad? What other useful results would this prevent us from proving?

Comment: @Mehrdad Like, everything? Local extremum, zero derivative implies constant function, $f'>0$ on an interval implies $f$ increasing, blah blah blah

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I'm confused, if this derivative is zero isn't the function still at a local extremum (for real-to-real functions)?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: By the way, it seems you're confusing my definition with that of the symmetric derivative. Note that the two are **not** the same! The symmetric derivative doesn't require the directional derivatives to exist in the first place, but mine does. The only difference is that mine doesn't require them to match in their values. So for example $x \mapsto \cos(1/x)$ would not be differentiable under my definition, but its symmetric derivative would be zero.

Comment: @Mehrdad They are the same assuming the directional derivatives exist. As I've said, the main problem is the failure of the MVT. I also don't quite understand the confusion you expressed in your second-to-last comment.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I think my last two comments might be related, but for the former comment, can you give me a counterexample to illustrate what you mean? For the latter comment, if they're really the same, what's the directional derivative of $x \mapsto \cos(1/x)$ in the positive direction? Isn't it undefined? And isn't the symmetric derivative of the same function zero?

Comment: @Mehrdad Read my comments more carefully. It's assuming the directional derivatives exist.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I did, and I still don't understand where it fails if they both exist. Why don't you just show me a counterexample to illustrate?

Comment: @Mehrdad What fails? The mean value theorem? $|x|$....

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: The failure of a zero derivative to imply a local  extremum, which was your first example?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Now that we know your first example was wrong, are you sure the second one is correct? Why wouldn't $f' > 0$ on an interval imply $f$ is increasing on that interval if you use my definition? Can you give a counterexample for that?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Local extremum never implied zero derivatives in the first place. It seems to me you're thinking too much in terms of the proofs you've seen rather than trying to get the intuition.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: No, it doesn't. Look at the counterexample regarding rationals and irrationals. It doesn't apply to mine. I keep telling you these are **not** the same thing and you keep ignoring me and insisting they are. They are *not*. Symmetric derivatives are looser than my notion of derivatives, and I already gave you clear examples of why. Can you just delete your comments? They're misleading everybody, including yourself.

Comment: @Mehrdad No, I would disagree with that. That was simply one example. The essence of Qiaochu's answer, the idea of the derivative as a local linear approximation, applies to your definition as well. The other answer is entirely fine.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: The linear approximation thing is hardly justification for lack of interest in this definition of the derivative. You could easily define some notion of "strict differentiability" (or whatever you want to call it) to mean the classical definition of differentiability, and use the strict derivative for the linear approximation. If anything, your wrong counterexamples showed why this definition of the derivative *is* interesting: it still preserves a lot of the original properties, just not all of them. So my question remains, perhaps even more strongly than before...

Comment: @Mehrdad And one of your previous comments was incorrect(I got confused because I thought it was the converse): local extremum (at $c$) does imply zero derivative (at $c$) with the standard definition of differentiability(this is Fermat's theorem); with your definition, it fails.

Comment: @Mehrdad Regarding your recent comment, well, then that's more of a philosophical issue. We can loosen the definition of anything with that logic (say we have some definition for $x$ and $y$ is a generalization of it).

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Local extremum doesn't even imply any kind of differentiability, let alone a zero derivative...

Comment: @Mehrdad Assuming $f$ differentiable, that is. Formally, let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real function and suppose $x_0 \in (a,b)$ is a local extremum and $f$ differentiable at $x_0$. Then $f'(x_0) = 0$. This fails with your definition.